# Fetch data for different time periods from the same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to get the data from couple of columns in a table for different time periods like current year and previous year based on another column(in the same table) having the date value.
I have used the same table twice using different aliases and a join as below:

```
SELECT  
NVL(SUM(a1.col1), 0) AS c1,
NVL(SUM(a1.col2), 0) AS c2,
NVL(SUM(a1.col3), 0) AS c3, 
NVL(SUM(a1.col4), 0) AS c4,
NVL(SUM(a2.col1), 0) AS o1,
NVL(SUM(a2.col2), 0) AS o2,
NVL(SUM(a2.col3), 0) AS o3, 
NVL(SUM(a2.col4), 0) AS o4 ,
b.u_id
FROM

    (SELECT *
    FROM a
    WHERE to_char(run_date, 'YYYY') = to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
    ) a1,

    (SELECT *
    FROM a
    WHERE to_char(run_date, 'YYYY') = to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') - 1
    ) a2,

    (SELECT u_id
    FROM b
    ) p

    WHERE a1.u_id (+) = b.u_id
    AND a2.u_id (+) = b.u_id
    GROUP BY b.u_id
```

Also tried refining the above query by limiting to use the table only once.
Query goes somewhat like this:

```
SELECT     
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'),a.col1, 0)), 0) AS c1,
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), a.col2, 0)), 0) AS c2,
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), a.col3, 0)), 0) AS c3, 
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), a.col4, 0)), 0) AS c4,
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')-1), a.col1, 0)), 0) AS p1,
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')-1), a.col2, 0)), 0) AS p2,
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')-1), a.col3, 0)), 0) AS p3, 
    NVL(SUM(DECODE(TO_CHAR(a.run_date, 'YYYY'), (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY')-1), a.col4, 0)), 0) AS p4,
    b.u_id 

    FROM a, b

    WHERE to_char(a.run_date, 'YYYY') IN (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'),(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') - 1))
    AND a.u_id = b.u_id     
    GROUP BY b.u_id
```

This runs a lil bit slow for large data. Can you suggest any alternate queries.?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd change:

```
WHERE to_char(a.run_date, 'YYYY') IN (to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'),(to_char(SYSDATE, 'YYYY') - 1))
```

to:

```
WHERE a.run_date >= add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'),-12) and
      a.run_date <  add_months(trunc(sysdate,'YYYY'), 12)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. im guessing that what you suggested should reduce the execution time based on the statement that date comparison is faster than converting the date to character format and comparing. but when i checked the query execution time its almost same. Say for example my previous query returned the results in 217secs. after modifying it with your change, it took around 216.55secs..

Comment: Post the explain plan, derived from running select * from table(dbms_xplan.display). You'll need to see whether a better plan is available, or whether you simply need a higher memory allocation for the group by. How many rows are returned from the query?

Comment: around 30k rows are returned by this query. Actually this is just a part of another query which is quite big. this code is used as one of the selecting tables in the main query.